# Sinatra changing default Directory apart from 'public/img'

Tags: ruby, directory, sinatra, default

In Sinatra application how to change the default directory path when concerned with taking images form another folder apart from the default directory '/public/images'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:root` option

> :root - The application’s root directory
>
> The directory used as a base for the application. By default, this is assumed to be the directory containing the main application file (:app_file setting). The root directory is used to construct the default :public_folder and :views settings. A common idiom is to set the :root setting explicitly in the main application file as follows:
>
> `set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)`

Read more [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration)

Comment: save_path="/{params[:intern_image[:filename]}"                                     In the above scenario  'save_path' is the parameter which i will be passing to the database('storing the path of that image into database') and  'intern_image' is the name of the input tag but cannot set it right as such, can you please help me out  @dax , Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SibuStephen, can you edit your original question with what you are trying to accomplish and include the code you're using now?